# urlmon.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, windows, mingw

При попытке вложить заголовок "urlmon.h" в программу на С и компиляции всего этого с помощью MinGW на Windows, возникает проблема:

```
C:\Users\ДМИТРИЙ\Desktop>gcc -o trigger.exe trigger.c -mwindows -static -lurlmon

trigger.c:2:19: фатальная ошибка: urlmon.h: No such file or directory
 #include<urlmon.h>
                   ^
компиляция прервана.
```

Я полагаю, что что-то надо установить, но что? В переменной PATH есть параметр с папкой MinGW, но компилятор всё ещё выдает ошибку. Что не так?

Comment: Лучше использовать libcurl

Answer (score 0):

> Я полагаю, что что-то надо установить, но что?

В доке про винду написано:

> urlmon.h header
> This header is used by Component Object Model (COM)

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/urlmon/

Вы собираетесь под люнихом использовать технологию СОМ ?